# Correct link in PHP error text

Tags: php, development-environment

On my `localhost` if I'm working on a project in http://localhost/**project_name**/ whenever I get an error or a warning it contains a link to the function but the link points to the wrong place, e.g. it points to http://localhost/**project_name**/function.rename

I have the many-HTML manual in http://localhost/php_manual/ is there a setting by which I instruct PHP to point to the correct place when it issues an error or a warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see [docref_root](http://docs.php.net/errorfunc.configuration#ini.docref-root)